# Turn off the red underline in just one file in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

How do I remove the red underline in just one file of Pycharm.
I'm writing a kivy application and the code works but there are the whole time these red underlines. How do I stop that?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the commentary #noqa like:

`blabla.do_something() #noqa`

But works only for one line

Comment: Thank you, but as you now I want for the whole file if possible.